# What is the analogue of 'circle through' for a disk?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

An example of `circle through` is shown on p. 65 of [the manual](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). I haven't been able to reproduce it for a disc.

This is more than a MWE but being new at `tikz` that's on purpose so people can point out inefficiencies in the way it is coded. For example, having declared `orig` as an image, can't I use it in the instruction using `img`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {calc}

\def\paramfont{\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries}
\def\paramradiusfactor{0.5}
\def\paramlabel{LABEL}
\def\paramradius{5}

\pgfdeclareimage
% [〈options〉]
{orig}{example-image-a.png}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \color{red}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,opacity=0.1] (img) at (9,9) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}; % TODO make use of orig
    \coordinate (nw) at (img.north west);
    \coordinate (ne) at (img.north east);
    \coordinate (sw) at (img.south west);
    \coordinate (se) at (img.south east);
    \coordinate (diskcenter) at ($(sw)!0.66!(ne)$);
    \def \diskradius{\paramradius*\paramradiusfactor}
    \coordinate (disklabel) at ($(diskcenter)+(0,\diskradius)$);
    \fill[yellow] (diskcenter) circle [radius=\diskradius]; % ?? through disklabel?
    \node[above] at (disklabel) {\paramfont\selectfont \paramlabel};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\usebox\mybox

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A disk is just a filled circle, isn't it? So if you can construct the circle with `through`, you can also fill it, can't you? In the example of the manual, you could use `\node [circle through=(B),label=left:$D$,fill=yellow] at (A) {};`

Comment: @user238301 You mean like this, `\draw [fill=yellow]`? Still, I know this code has redundancies, and I want to see an efficient way to do it.

Comment: @user238301 Your suggestion gives me "I do not know the key '/tikz/circle through'¨

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `circle through`, but you need to load the `through` library beforehand. Then you can type `\node[fill=yellow, circle through=(disklabel)] at (diskcenter) {\paramfont\selectfont\paramlabel};` for example.

To make a reference to your previously defined image, you should use `\pgfuseimage`.

Ti*k*Z already loads the `xcolor` package. You don't need to load it again (except for the case that you need it in your preamble for something you want to define before you load Ti*k*Z).

Since you aim for reducing redundancies and superfluous code: I removed `\color{red}` as it is of no use in this example. Also, you could directly write `\coordinate (diskcenter) at ($(img.south west)!0.66!(img.north east)$);` and skip the four definitions of the coordinates. At least, you don't use the `north west` and the `south east` coordinate in your example, so you can delete those.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, through}

\def\paramfont{\color{white}\sffamily\bfseries}
\def\paramradiusfactor{0.5}
\def\paramlabel{LABEL}
\def\paramradius{5}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=\textwidth]{orig}{example-image-a.png}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,opacity=0.1] (img) at (9,9) {\pgfuseimage{orig}}; 
    \coordinate (nw) at (img.north west);
    \coordinate (ne) at (img.north east);
    \coordinate (sw) at (img.south west);
    \coordinate (se) at (img.south east);
    \coordinate (diskcenter) at ($(sw)!0.66!(ne)$);
    \def\diskradius{\paramradius*\paramradiusfactor}
    \coordinate (disklabel) at ($(diskcenter)+(0,\diskradius)$);
    \node[fill=yellow, circle through=(disklabel)] at (diskcenter) {\paramfont\selectfont\paramlabel}; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\usebox\mybox

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, just one misreading of mine: the label is supposed to come above `disklabel`, not `discenter`.

Comment: Reply to m/s: `\coordinate[label=above:LABEL` (disklabel)...`